# AJAX Request & Return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, upload, request

I'm creating a "new blog" form and I have a few photo upload fields in the form. Is there a way I can send the post request using AJAX, uploading the photo, and return the photos url to display on the "new blog" form? My back end is written in ruby on rails.

I hope that makes sense! Any help greatly appreciated it!

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it's a little complicated. The problem is that you cannot send uploaded files via AJAX, BUT there is a straightforward workaround which most people use.

This is how it works: You upload the photo into an invisible iFrame. You set this iframe as the upload form's target, and the user will be able to submit the form without reloading the page.

Example:

```
<iframe id="upload"></iframe>
<%= form_for @photo, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => 'photo_upload_form', :target => 'upload' }, :url => photos_path do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image, 'Upload Photo' %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>    
<% end %>
```

...and of course use CSS to hide the iFrame. I think I once had an issue with hiding the iFrame with `display: none`, so I would recommend moving it off-screen by using something like:

```
#upload { position: absolute; left: -10px; top: -10px; width: 1px; height: 1px; }
```

Finally, you can use JavaScript in the view which is rendered inside the hidden iFrame via `window.parent`, so this way you can actually display the uploaded image inside the upload form.

Comment: ah interesting, I am doing something similar currently. Just putting the photo form inside an iframe then when you submit the photo the frame redirects to the uploaded photo.

Could you not just send back the photos url? e.g. example.com/uploads/test.jpg ???

Comment: Sure there are many different ways to implement this, but I think the easiest way is to use only one iFrame that's completely hidden. Whether you write JS code inside that iFrame's view or whether you send an URL and have the JS in the original view, that's up to you.